# In the triangle $ABC$, if $a=\frac{2(b^2-c^2)}{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4c^2}}$, prove that $3\cdot\widehat{C}=2\cdot\widehat{B}$.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Just like in the title, I have to prove that if in a triangle $ABC$

$$a=\frac{2(b^2-c^2)}{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4c^2}}$$
holds, then $3\cdot\widehat{C}=2\cdot\widehat{B}$.

---

The denominator of the big fraction looks like the positive solution
of a quadratic equation, specifically  $x^2 + bx - c^2 = 0$, so the claim appears to be that if $ x = \frac{b^2-c^2}{a}$ is a solution of that equation, then $\frac{\widehat{C}}{\widehat{B}}=\frac{2}{3}$.

I have not gone beyond this examination of the problem itself, but
perhaps this will give you some ideas to try.

Comment: Please any one help

Comment: Oh I saw it now I mean 3 times measure of angle C= 2 times measure of angle B

Comment: I want any one help me

Comment: Could you help me please

Comment: I started,
but my attempt lead to a dead end.
I'll show what I did
and hope that
my work might
aid someone else.


If
$x^2+bx-c^2
= 0
$,
then
$x 
=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2+4c^2}}{2}
=\frac{b^2-c^2}{a}
$
if we take the
positive root.
So
$ax = b^2-c^2
$.

By the cosine law,
$\cos(B)
=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}
$
and
$\cos(C)
=\frac{b^2+a^2-c^2}{2ab}
$.

So
$\cos(B)
=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}
=\frac{a^2-ax}{2ac}
=\frac{a-x}{2c}
$
and
$\cos(C)
=\frac{b^2+a^2-c^2}{2ab}
=\frac{a^2+ax}{2ab}
=\frac{a+x}{2b}
$.

We have
$\cos(2z) = 2\cos^2(z)-1
$
and
$\cos(3z)

Comment: there is no point in begging for help. Please give a proper formatting to your question by using $\LaTeX$. We will be glad to provide help once the question is readable, at least.

Comment: Given a triangle ABC, if $$a = \dfrac{2(b^2 - c^2)}{-b + \sqrt{b^2 + 4c^2}}$$, prove that 
$3m(C) = 2m(B)$.

Comment: To your question, not to your comments. By the way, I did it in your place.

Comment: Really thanks a lot for you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $\widehat{ C}=2\theta, \widehat{B}=3\theta,\widehat{A}=\pi-5\theta$ and $R=1$ (the circumradius) we have:
$$ a = 2\sin(5\theta),\quad b=2\sin(3\theta),\quad c=2\sin(2\theta) $$
and $\frac{b^2-c^2}{a}=2\sin\theta$. On the other hand,
$$ \sin^2(\theta) + \sin(3\theta)\sin(\theta)-\sin^2(2\theta)=0.$$

Comment: I want to start with the big fraction and end with the ratio between angles not the opposite

Comment: @AhmedAhmed: you have to exploit nothing more than what is written above, you just have to "reverse the order" of the proof. Assuming that $a=2R\sin\widehat{A}$ fullfills $\ldots$, by setting $\sin\theta=\frac{b^2-c^2}{a}$ it follows that $\ldots$, hence $\widehat{A}=\pi-5\theta,\widehat{B}=3\theta,\widehat{C}=2\theta$ follows.

Comment: Would you please to write it to understand you and I will pleased for you

Comment: @AhmedAhmed: I beg your pardon if I sound rude, but I think I did pretty much yet: I improved your question, provided an answer and explained it in the comments, without getting any reputation in the process. I am not really that interested in rep. points, but I think it would be better for you to spend some time in thinking to what I wrote instead of asking for more details. Everything needed is already there, I swear.

Comment: Thank you very much I'm really pleased for your connection